# How can I Group By Month from a Date field

Tags: python, pandas, date, data-cleaning

I have a data frame similar to this one

```
| date      | Murders  | State  |
|-----------|--------- |------- |
| 6/2/2017  | 100      | Ags    |
| 5/23/2017 | 200      | Ags    |
| 5/20/2017 | 300      |  BC    |
| 6/22/2017 | 400      |  BC    |
| 6/21/2017 | 500      |  Ags   |
```

I would like to group the above data by month and state to get an output as:

```
| date      | Murders(SUM)  | State  |
|-----------|---------      |------- |
| January   | 100           | Ags    |
| February  | 200           | Ags    |
| March     | 300           | Ags    |
|    ....   | ....          | Ags    | 
| January   | 400           |  BC    |
| February  | 500           |  BC    |
  ....         ....            ..
```

I tried with this:

```
dg = DF.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).sum() # groupby each 1 month
dg.index = dg.index.strftime('%B')
```

But these lines are only add the murders by month but without taking in count the State

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do

```
df.groupby([pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.strftime('%B'),df.State]).Murders.sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: The result of my column "date" is `1`, `1`, `1`... `12`